# Aligning same variables below each other

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, alignment

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
   x_1 & {}+{} &  6x_2 & {}+{} & 2x_3 & {} -{} & 5x_4 & {} -{} &  2x_5 & {} = {} & -4 \\
    2x_3 & {} - {} &  8x_4 & {} - {} &  x_5 & {}={} &  3 \\
    x_5 & {} ={} & 7
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

I want to align $x_5$ under $x_5$ in all lines. Also, I want to leave a white space below $x_1$ as I do not have $x_1$ in the second and third equation and similarly for $x_2$. Could anyone help me in doing so please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for the [systeme](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/systeme) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}

\sysalign{r,r} % right-alignment on both sides of '=' symbols
\sysdelim..    % no delimiters

\[
\systeme{ x_1+6x_2+2x_3-5x_4-2x_5=-4 , 2x_3-8x_4-x_5=3 , x_5=7 }
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It did not work with me by system before posting the question, but let me give it a try again

Comment: yeah I was not using the systeme package at that time

Answer (score 5):

Here's an [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) way with `alignat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{6}
    x_1 + {}&&  6x_2 + {}&& 2x_3 - {}&& 5x_4 - {}&& 2x_5 = {}&& -4 \\
            &&           && 2x_3 - {}&& 8x_4 - {}&&  x_5 = {}&&  3 \\
            &&           &&          &&          &&  x_5 = {}&&  7
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution based on the `array` environment with an extra space next to the `=`, which may be preferable:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{array}{*4{rc} r @{{\ }={}} r}
        x_1 &+& 6x_2 &+& 2x_3 &-& 5x_4 &-& 2x_5 & -4 \\
            & &      & & 2x_3 &-& 8x_4 &-&  x_5 &  3 \\
            & &      & &      & &      & &  x_5 &  7
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]